# Which class of polymerization reactions reaches high conversion under one second?

Tags: kinetics, polymers

Are there polymerization reactions that can reach high conversion very fast, say under 1 s? i.e. to polymerize "immediately"?

Comment: The closest thing that comes to mind is the [explosive polymerization of 4-nitroaniline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4pNXAtPJp8), though it takes more than a second, and the product has a poorly defined structure.

Comment: Nylon also polymerizes pretty quickly

Comment: @Benzene, how quick?

Comment: https://youtu.be/T0ndxrYD1WM